# What can I do to prevent the undefined offset notice in my code?

Tags: php, upload, undefined, offset

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 6

line 6 is the following:

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
```

Here's all you should need:

```
session_start();
//Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']); $i++) {
  //Get the temp file path
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

  //Make sure we have a filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    //Setup our new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploaded_files/" . $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

    echo "Upload Successful!<br />";

}
}
}
```

Comment: We'll need more code to actually help you. With this snippet I can only guess that the index for the integer that is in $i does not exists...

Comment: I added more. That should give you enough to work with. Think you can help? Even if it's just suppressing the notice because the code works perfectly, I just can't have this showing up whenever someone uploads something.

Comment: Does the form actually upload more then one file? If not the for loop doesn't make much sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if it exists:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]))
{
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
}
```

Comment: that created more problems actually

Comment: No my mistake, I had done something wrong when entering the code. It works thanks

Comment: Thats not a solution.. surpressing notices never is, fixing notices is.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance your code in the for() loop should read:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++)
```

Because the items counted in `$_FILES['file']` can be a different count than the items
counted in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

If the count of items in `$_FILES['file']` is more than items counted in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` then your code will trigger an error with a notice of undefined offset.

If the count of items in `$_FILES['file']` is less than items counted in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` then your code will not see all data beyond that initial count that is 
higher in the `['tmp_name']` array.

It is Best to keep the incrementing variable/ operator of the for loop nearest the array/sub-array you are counting in the expression.

A key trick to remember this easily is to notice that the for loop will look nearly the same as the indexed/associated location of the array you place into a variable.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']); $i++)  
$tmpFilePath   =   $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
```

See it?